# Building and using Boost for Windows Visual Studio with a custom ICU

Tags: visual-c++, boost, icu, uima

I have been trying for a few days to build a project based on UIMA C++ framework (http://uima.apache.org/). I am currently using the version 2.4.0 release candidate 6, which comes with Linux and Windows binaries to have all dependancies easily bundled.

In particular, it comes with binary libraries for ICU (3.6 I believe).

In my project, I am building a C++ UIMA annotator and my code makes use of Boost C++ library v1.51.0.

Everything compiles fine but at runtime, I get Access Violation exceptions when starting to use, let's say operator <<(ostream&, const icu::UnicodeString&). It may be a problem of version incompatibility between Boost and UIMA C++.

So, I'm trying to recompile Boost on my machine, telling it to reuse the ICU that comes along with UIMA C++, but there seems to be a problem with MSVC toolset because I always get messages telling me there is no ICU available when building Boost:

```
c:\Users\Sylvain\boost_1_51_0>b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 variant=release -sICU_LINK=c:\users\sylvain\apache-uima\uimacpp

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes
    - x86                      : yes
    - has_icu builds           : no
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - iconv (libc)             : no
    - iconv (separate)         : no
    - icu                      : no
    - icu (lib64)              : no
    - gcc visibility           : no
    - long double support      : yes
```

Has anyone managed to build Boost with the -sICU_PATH options and MSVC?

Thanks,
Sylvain

Answer (score 1):

Just had to build Boost with ICU (and succeeded). Since this question is one of the first results on google (and not of very much help right now), I decided to share what I learned.

I was doing an x64 build of Boost 1.56 with MSVC11 (Visual Studio 2012), linking against a custom build of ICU 4.8.1.

First of all, Boost's directory detection for ICU seems a little weird. Here is what my final layout for the ICU directory looked like:

```
my_icu_root
  +- bin
  +- bin64
  +- include
     +- layout
     +- unicode
  +- lib
  +- lib64
```

I copied all ICU dlls (both Debug and Release versions) to `bin`, all libs (again Debug and Release) to `lib` and all header files to `include`. To make `bjam` happy, I also had to copy the *full* `bin` and `lib` directories to `bin64` and `lib64` respectively. Without both directories, either detection of ICU or compilation of Boost.Locale would fail on my machine.

With this layout, all I had to do was to add `-sICU_PATH=<my_icu_root>` to my usual `bjam` command line to get it to build.

You know that Boost successfully detected ICU if you get both

```
 - has_icu builds           : yes
[...]
 - icu                      : yes
```

during configuration.

Here is some advice if, for some reason, it does not work right away.

Bjam caches configure information to `bin.v2/project-cache.jam`. If you try to re-run Bjam after a failed configuration, *be sure to delete that file first*. Otherwise bjam might decide to just skip ICU detection altogether (you will see lots of `(cached)` in the console output).

If configuration fails, take a look at `bin.v2/config.log` to get detailed information on what went wrong. Most likely, it was unable to compile the test program at `libs/regex/build/has_icu_test.cpp`. This log contains the command line of the build command, which is usually enough to find out what went wrong. If the log seems suspiciously empty, you probably forgot to delete the `project-cache.jam`.

Finally, a successful configure run is no guarantee for a successful build. On my machine, I managed to configure everything correctly but still had Boost.locale fail during build because of missing `lib` files. So be sure to check the build output for failed or skipped targets.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting has_icu builds : yes and icu : yes.  I'm able to compile the boost has_icu_test.cpp but if I try building, I get the following error: has_icu.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _u_charFromName_53.  I am including the path to ICU\include and ICU\lib for the lib path.  Am I supposed to be adding some of the specific .lib files to the Input / Additional Dependencies options?  Please advise.

Comment: Where is the `bjam` ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a boost/libs/regex/build/has_icu_test.cpp. I can't remember the fix/issue off the top of my head but you should be able to cheat and simply return 0 from main() there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Boost doesn't work with a six year old ICU. Can you rebuild UIMA instead?

Answer (score 0):

My command line as follows:

```
bjam -sICU_PATH=c:\icu --toolset=msvc-10.0 variant=release stage
```

Just look into \bin.v2\config.log

It contains exact error. In my case it was absence of specific library for linking

```
...found 10 targets...
...found 3 targets...
...found 66 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
msvc.link bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\has_icu.exe
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'icuind.lib'
```

The problem is - boost build anyway looks for debug library even when requested for variant=release.

Comment: what you pasted has \debug\ in it, so it seems that it attempted to build debug.

Comment: will double check it tomorrow. it is possible that it was old log from --build-type=complete and bjam just use cached values. but anyway the issue can be found using config.log from my answer.

Comment: @Steven R. Loomis just checked my assumption on clean build - configuration done with debug but build starts with release. So my assumption is correct and looks like it is a bug in boost build.

Comment: Hi, where is `bjam` ?

Comment: @linrongbin reference in [Getting Started guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/more/getting_started/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. And the way I choose to work around it is to make a copy of icuin.lib and name it as icuind.lib, and so for other libs. Then bjam says it has found icu.

Comment: That could work.  In practice, you can't link against the real icuin.lib and run with icuind.dll or vice versa, but if it's just a matter of the wrong linkage at link time it should be fine.  Kind of scary that this code is otherwise attempting to use the debug ICU for production use.